# HTML SVG text selection in Chromium not working

Tags: html, svg, text, selection, chromium

I have a problem - when I try to select a text in  element, only the first character gets highlighted. I'm running  Chromium 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). Problem does not exist on Firefox.
Basic HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <svg version="1.1">
    <g>
      <text y=20>
        wabalabadub dub
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Text should be selected whole.]

When I doubleclick a word, it gets selected whole, but I need to be able to select more than 1 word. 
So, does anyone know a solution to this problem? Or a workaround:)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try to use `user-select: all;` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, its a bug in Chromium - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897752 . Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

The error seeems to be visual in nature: Ctrl-c to the clipboard, and not only the highlighted letter is there, but everything you moved your mouse over; even extending/reducing your selection with Shift+arrow seems to work correctly.

The best I can come up with for now is to style the selection, but choices seem to be limited:

```
text::selection { fill:blue }
```

is more or less the only one that I got to work, but supresses all background coloration (in Chromium, Firefox ignores the rule). `background-color`, `text-decoration` or `font-weight` properties have no effect, unfortunately.